# Create a new row in DataGrid in a specific position in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview, datagridview, datagrid

I am working with vb.net and I have an object DataRow, with attributes name, surname, age, salary. I have added 50 of these objects to a list of DataRow, then
 grid.dataSource = list of DataRow objects to populate a grid.

Id like to make so that after selecting a row on the grid, I can click a button and a new row (a copy of the selected one) is created in the grid just after the selected row. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Well, it depends a little.  There are few approaches.  Assuming that your data source list isn't you could simply use the list.Insert method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netcore-3.1  If your datasource is ordered by some value, or done via the datagridview or something, it becomes a little more complicated and probably will need more detail on how that is acchived

Answer (score 0):

Just sort your grid by something uniquey, by default. The new row will have the same value as the existing row and when inserted and hence end up sorted near the old item. Whether it ends up before or after the old row doesn't matter so much because they are clones of each other

If you plan on offering the user the option to sort and they might sort by something not very unique, you'll need to keep the grid sorted better by having a second level of sorting that is unique.

One approach to this might be to have an incremented SortOrder as part of the data (incremented in some sensible order eg by name)  and every time the grid is sorted by X, add a second sort level referencing SortOrder. When adding a new row, make the clone's SortOrder to be a plus one of the row that was cloned and adjust the other higher SortOrder values up by one

---

In ui terms it's probably better to have a bunch of text/number/date/combo/check boxes etc that the user types values into and then clicks Add; the individual controls can have better functionality than typing into the grid